# Sendgrid Node.js library doesn't work with React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, sendgrid

I need help. I'm trying to use node.js to handle sending emails out on my website. I want my email form to go ahead and send out the email on submit instead of using the basic "mailto" action. I have Sendgrid as my email service to handle the API and other server-side tasks.

I keep getting this error and I think it's a Webpack issue. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdG71.png)
I'll also post a few lines of code.

Do you have any ideas on what I can do?

//Webpack.config file

```
 "use strict";
var webpack = require('webpack');
var loaders = require('./webpack.loaders');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const HOST = process.env.HOST || "127.0.0.1";
const PORT = process.env.PORT || "8888";

// global css
loaders.push({
    test: /[\/\\](node_modules|global)[\/\\].*\.css$/,
    loaders: [
        'css-loader!autoprefixer-loader?browsers=last 2 versions',
        'style-loader!css-loader!autoprefixer-loader',
        'style?sourceMap',
        'css'
    ]
});
//local sass modules
loaders.push({
    test: /[\/\\]src[\/\\].*\.sass/,
    loaders: [
        'style?sourceMap',
        'css-loader!autoprefixer-loader?browsers=last 2 versions',
        'style-loader!css-loader!autoprefixer-loader',
        'css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
        'sass'
    ]
});
//local css modules
loaders.push({
    test: /[\/\\]src[\/\\].*\.css/,
    loaders: [
        'style?sourceMap',
        'css-loader!autoprefixer-loader?browsers=last 2 versions',
        'style-loader!css-loader!autoprefixer-loader',
        'css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
    ]
});

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        `webpack-dev-server/client?http://${HOST}:${PORT}`,
        `webpack/hot/only-dev-server`,
        `./src/index.jsx` // Your appʼs entry point
    ],
    devtool: process.env.WEBPACK_DEVTOOL || 'cheap-module-source-map',
    output: {
        path:__dirname,
        filename: './src/bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        loaders
    },
    devServer: {
        // do not print bundle build stats
        noInfo: true,
        // enable HMR
        hot: true,
        // embed the webpack-dev-server runtime into the bundle
        inline: true,
        // serve index.html in place of 404 responses to allow HTML5 history
        historyApiFallback: true,
        port: PORT,
        host: HOST
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    ]
};
```

Comment: in console in project directory can you try `npm install --save-dev bluebird`  and try again?

Comment: I did that and I still get the second error. That the module couldn't be parsed.

Comment: looks like its an open issue https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/issues/289

Comment: Well, I guess I'll have to find another way. I can't wait for this to be solved. Thanks for your help, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the solution to this

This isn't an issue on this repos end, your webpack config just needs a json loader, see this issue:

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/303

I resolved myself adding `{ test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json'}` to my webpackloaders

you also may need to do `npm install json-loader --module-bind json`